# Change Directory with Errorformat

Tags: quickfix, makeprg, errorformat

I'm trying to write an `errorformat` for JUnit. Directory structure from `cwd` is:

```
unsw/piazza/PiazzaForum.java
unsw/piazza/Thread.java
unsw/test/PiazzaTest.java
```

Amongst all the cruft outputted by JUnit, relevant output lines looks like: `unsw.test.PiazzaTest.testSearchByTag(PiazzaTest.java:50)`

I capture this with `let &errorformat = '%.%#unsw\.test%.%#(%f:%l)'`
This expects `PiazzaTest.java` to be in the `cwd` when it is not.

How can I solve this?

Comment: How would you tell `&efm` which directory the file is in?  I suspect you may be better served by having the output give you the path (I don't use JUnit so can't advise on how to do so).

Comment: Possibilities: use `%D` and `%X` to handle the package names as directories or post-process JUnit's output (externally w/ script or internally w/ QuickfixCmdPost, see `:help QuickfixCmdPost-example`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although not very flexible:

*run-tests.bash*:

```
echo "Entering dir '$(pwd)/unsw/test'" 
java -jar ../lib/junit-platform-console-standalone-1.7.0-M1.jar \
        -cp . --scan-class-path --disable-banner --details=summary
echo "Leaving dir"
```

*.vimrc*:

```
let &errorformat = 
 \ "%.%#unsw\.test%.%#(%f:%l),"
 \. "%DEntering dir '%f',%XLeaving dir,"
```